# Maven warning compiler and jar plugin missing

Tags: maven, netbeans

In netbeans i'm trying to run jasperreport-5.2.0 downloaded from jasperreport website
but i'm getting the following warning and error

**warning**
build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing
build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing

then the netbean compiler shows the error message

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Final Memory: 19M/63M

i'd tried increasing the heap size, but couldn't resolve the problem

How can i get rid of this problem..?

Comment: Please provide your POM.xml

Comment: ArunM
<plugin></br>
- <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId></br>
- <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId></br>
                     
- <configuration></br>
*  <source>1.6</source></br>
*  <target>1.6</target></br>
- </configuration></br>
</plugin></br>
<plugin></br>
- <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId></br>
- <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId></br>
- <configuration></br>
*  <archive></br>
-*   <manifestFile>${basedir}/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile></br>
*  </archive></br>
- </configuration></br>
</plugin></br>

Comment: You are having that warning because you are not including the plugin version:
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
however, that is only a warning and not the source of your problem. What are you trying to do? "run jasperreport-5.2.0" is kind of ambiguous, it is a library not a standalone program.